# CallDirectoryExtension has an error during user use [loading indefinitely]

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, callkit, call-directory-extension

I'm using the Call Identification utility to identify incoming calls, but during use, some of my users have encountered an error as shown below.

[image]

Is there any solution for this situation? Can I refresh the extension to its original state so users can continue to use it?

My code:

```
override func beginRequest(with context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {
context.delegate = self
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
// Check whether this is an "incremental" data request. If so, only provide the set of phone number blocking
// and identification entries which have been added or removed since the last time this extension's data was loaded.
// But the extension must still be prepared to provide the full set of data at any time, so add all blocking
// and identification phone numbers if the request is not incremental.

if let lastIndentifyUpdate = defaults.object(forKey: "lastIndentifyUpdate") as? Date, context.isIncremental {
  addOrRemoveIncrementalIdentificationPhoneNumbers(to: context, since: lastIndentifyUpdate)
} else {
  addAllIdentificationPhoneNumbers(to: context)
}

defaults.set(Date(), forKey:"lastIndentifyUpdate")

context.completeRequest()
}

// Record the most-recently loaded set of identification entries in data store for the next incremental load...
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: There is a good chance your extension has crashed.  A common reason for the extension crashing is out of memory - Extensions have a much smaller memory quota that your main app. How many numbers are you attempting to load? How are you storing the numbers to load?  If you have more than a few thousand, Core Data will use too much memory.

Comment: @Paulw11 Hi you, i'm using file txt, with about 15000 numbers, every 20 minutes i will reload all those 15000 numbers or more once to get new numbers

Comment: It is definitely worth determining the delta in your main app and creating a delta text file for your extension to use and only reloading the whole file when required

Comment: @Paulw11 Hi Paul, because I am providing users with the auto update feature in the background (The extension seems to be crashing because my user turned on the auto update feature, I'm sure of it), with Apple's learning system it seems that it will activate once every 20 minutes, with each activation I redownload the txt file with more than 15000 numbers.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11, I'm in a situation where I added 15,000 numbers before, then I added 150 new numbers and the numbers in 15,000 are no longer recognized. Do you know the reason? It took me 2 days to find the reason but it didn't work, I debugged in the extension but my breakpoint didn't stop at any error point Yes, thank you very much

Comment: And what happens when 1 or more numbers in the new 150 numbers already exist in the previous 15000 numbers?

Comment: If you are providing an [incremental](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxcalldirectoryextensioncontext/2891625-isincremental)  update then any numbers you provide are either added or updated the number if it already already exists when you call `addIdentificationEntry` and you remove deleted numbers using `removeIdentificationEntry`

Comment: Yes exactly, I'm also using the same method as you mentioned above, but for some reason my old numbers that were added before are no longer recognized.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to show relevant code from your extension

Comment: Yes, i'm edited, Please let me know where I am wrong

Comment: Is the `reporters` array sorted by phone number ascending?  You must add new numbers in increasing order.

Comment: I'm sure it's sorting in ascending order, because I get no errors due to entriesOutOfOrder including duplicateEntries

Comment: Do you think my processing code above slows down the processing? because I'm using 2 for loops

Comment: No.  What is your data source? A text file?  Most problems with the directory extension happen due to the limited memory available.

Comment: Yes, my data source is a text file, I also guess that it exceeds the memory, but my text file only has 9 numbers so it is too small to exceed this memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256445/discussion-between-paulw11-and-a-programer).

Comment: I just updated my question to add the code to read my txt file, please take a look

Comment: Hi Paul, I just discovered that if a new element matches both the number and label that was added before, the extension will fail, not be deleted as discussed before.

Comment: Ok good. So it seems you need to manage your change detection